# How to validate infix notation in javascript?

Tags: javascript, validation, expression, comparison-operators, infix-notation

I have an infix expression: `((attribute1*attribute2)/attribute3+attribute4)`

It may vary according to the user input. I want to check whether the expression is valid.

Valid example: `((attribute1*attribute2)/attribute3+attribute4)`

Invalid example: `(attrribute1*attribute2+*(attribute3)`

The second one has no closing parenthesis; also the `*` operator is not needed. How can I perform this sort of validation in javascript?

Now this is my regex:

```
/ *\+? *\-? *[a-zA-Z0-9]+ *( *[\+\-\*\/\=\<\>\!\&\|\%] *\+? *\-? *[a-zA-Z0-9]+ *)*/
```

I need a regex for comparison operators like `<=` , `>=` , `!=` , `==` etc. How can I implement this?

Answer (score 4):

You could try something like this:

```
function validateInfix(infix) {
    var balance = 0;
    // remove white spaces to simplify regex
    infix = infix.replace(/\s/g, '');

    // if it has empty parenthesis then is not valid
    if (/\(\)/.test(infix)) {
        return false;
    }

    // valid values: integers and identifiers
    var value = '(\\d+|[a-zA-Z_]\\w*)';
    // the unary '+' and '-'
    var unaryOper = '[\\+\\-]?';
    // the arithmetic operators
    var arithOper = '[\\+\\-\\*\\/]';
    // the comparison operators
    var compOper = '(\\<\\=?|\\>\\=?|\\=\\=|\\!\\=)';

    // if it has more than one comparison operator then is not valid
    if (infix.match(new RegExp(compOper, 'g')).length > 1) {
        return false;
    }

    // the combined final regex: /[\+\-]?(\d+|[a-zA-Z_]\w*)(([\+\-\*\/]|(\<\=?|\>\=?|\=\=|\!\=))[\+\-]?(\d+|[a-zA-Z_]\w*))*/
    var regex = new RegExp(unaryOper + value + '((' + arithOper + '|' + compOper + ')' + unaryOper + value + ')*');

    // validate parenthesis balance
    for (var i = 0; i < infix.length; i++) {
        if (infix[i] == '(') {
            balance++;
        }
        else if (infix[i] == ')') {
            balance--;
        }

        if (balance < 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    if (balance > 0) {
        return false;
    }

    // remove all the parenthesis
    infix = infix.replace(/[\(\)]/g, '');

    return regex.test(infix);
}
```

The idea is to check first the parenthesis balance, then remove them all given that we only want to validate and not evaluate, and then match the remaining expression to a regex (which may not be perfect, I'm not a regex expert). And... just in case: `infix` argument must be a string.

### Edit

I noticed a couple of details and changed the code a bit:

1. Added the operators you needed the regex to match too.
2. Removed white spaces to get rid of regex junk.
3. Checked if the expression had empty parenthesis.
4. Checked if the expression had more than one comparison operators.
5. Changed this `\+?\-?` by this `[\+\-]?`.
6. Changed [string `match` method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp) by [regex `test` method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_test.asp) where possible.
7. Changed this `[a-zA-Z0-9]` by this `(\d+|[a-zA-Z_]\w*)` since the first one matches wrong identifiers like `53abc`.
8. For better understanding and clarity, extracted pieces of regex into separate variables and built the final one from these.

Hope this is ok for you now :)

Comment: Thanks ecampver ! Now this is my regex, `var regex = / *\+? *\-? *[a-zA-Z0-9]+ *( *[\+\-\*\/\=\<\>\!\&\|\%] *\+? *\-? *[a-zA-Z0-9]+ *)*/;` I need a regex for comparison operators like <= , >= , != , == etc? How can I implement This?

Comment: @sri: Edited my answer, check it out and if you find with any other problem just ask ;)

Comment: @sri: Well? Did this answer help you? Please some feedback would be good.